# Wix installer: How to update .properties files (JAVA - Non Xml)?

Tags: java, wix

Using Wix (3.10) installer, I am developing a setup project which required to deploy .war (Java Project) file on Tomcat server and then **Update config.properties file having connection details and other information**.

**Is there any way to update `config.properties` file?**

Config.properties file:

```
dbpassword=password
database=localhost
dbuser=xxxx
```

Comment: Please add a sample config.properties file.

Comment: Please no external link, all relevant info should be in the question itself. You don't need to add whole file, a few lines showcasing the general format will be enough.